# Ubuntu on ARM platforms, ZYBO in concret

Tags: software-installation, arm, docker

I need to boot ubuntu on my ZYBO platform. Is there any compatible bootable ubuntu image with this platform to download? Where can I found it? Is there any manual to follow in order to take the right steps?

I also need to install docker in this ubuntu version, would it be possible or it depends on the ubuntu version?

Looking forward to any answer,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are official instructions from the manufacturer [here](https://reference.digilentinc.com/learn/programmable-logic/tutorials/zybo-zybot-guide/start#installing_and_unpacking_linaro) on installing Linaro Ubuntu, which is specifically maintained for ARM systems.

As for Docker, Docker support depends on your specific kernel. It should run fine on your system.